# IDE - Regex find unique

Tags: regex

If this is not the right stack for this kind of question, please point me in the right direction.

I use KomodoIDE.  I'm trying to clean up a WordpressDB that's been passed around on a bunch of hosts, so the url's embedded in the content are all over the place.

I'm looking for a way in an IDE, not necessarily just Komodo, to get a listing of unique values for a given regex.  The regex I have so far is pretty simple:

```
(http://)\w+
```

What I'd like to do is produce a list of these unique values.  I would presume this is a function of the IDE.  I've come across articles on how to do this, but they don't seem to abide by the "negative lookahead".

```
(http://)(?!.*\\1\b)\w+
```

Comment: So, try `((http://)\w+)(?!.*\1.*$)`.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the kind of thing that an IDE would do. You can search for all instances of a regexp, so you can find and edit them, but just listing the unique values isn't really part of editing. This would be easier to do with command line tools like `grep` and `uniq`.

Comment: @stribizhev Tried it, and it seems to work like the simple one, but I'm not sure to get it to return unique.  http://regexr.com/3aven  In that example, `http://foo` should only be hilighted once, correct?

Comment: @tPlummer: You are testing in JavaScript regex tester, thus, try http://regexr.com/3avet : `((http://)\w+)(?![\s\S]*\1[\s\S]*$)`